# R package CMD check errors

Tags: r, bioconductor, rstudio

I have written some codes in R for my personal use. The package successfully installed on my personal laptop (where I have written those commands) and working correctly. But when I distributed it to my other colleagues, this package is not installing and returned these errors.

```
In R CMD INSTALL 

Warning in install.packages : running command

"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program

Files\R\R-3.4.3\library" "E:/test/Gene_1.0.tar.gz"' had status 1

Warning in install.packages :   installation of package

E:/test/Gene_1.0.tar.gz had non-zero exit status
```

Secondly, I ran "CHECK PACKAGE" command in R-studio. Those results expressed two errors and two notes.

```
> checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
  Dependence on R version '3.5.1' not with patchlevel 0

> checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
   WARNING
  'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
0 errors v | 2 warnings x | 2 notes x

Error: R CMD check found WARNINGs

Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Kindly help me out with these two issues.

Comment: The R version is probably too old, update it (or decrease the R version mentioned in your code to 3.4 or older).